Copy file under impersonated user in Windows not always works
I need to copy a file from the user's temp folder under impersonated user. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. For example: if virtual machine is multiuser it may not work for some users. If virtual machine is single user it works. What may be the case?
My process looks like:

Under logged user I get his temp folder.

In this temp folder I create a folder. On that folder I give permisssion for impersonated user via:
function SetDocumentBufferFolderPermission(const path, user: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  if AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(PWideChar(path), SE_FILE_OBJECT, PWideChar(user), TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
     GENERIC_ALL, GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT) = NOERROR then
    Result := True;
end;


Then in that folder I create another folder and copy the file into it.

Then I impersonate the user and try to copy this file to another place. In some cases it is successfull, in some cases it is not. Error is:

Access is denied



I added logs to check every part of the path on that parts where the impersonated user has access (checking with DirectoryExists function). The impersonated user has rights on all folders except C:\Users\<UserName>~1. But that right is the same on users where my procedure works and where it doesn't.

Why do I have a feeling that you are designing some kind of malware?

I don' t know. It's not a mailware. it's a tasktracker. An user adds file for a task. File goes to remote file server. But user shouldn't have access to that remove file server. That's why I need system user that will copy this file from temporary path to source.

Are these task files created by your application or by some 3rd party application. If it is the former than you should consider in developing a multi-tiered system where your Client application communicates with Server application in order to upload or download specific data. This data can be anything from single database records to whole files. Delphi supports several different API's to achieve this like REST API or Datasnap. But if those files are created by a 3rd party app you should consider developing a system service that will do the file copying. ...

... Modern Windows versions (Vista nad newer) allows executing services with different privileges which gives you a fine control of what such service can do and what not.
